# mysql_affected_rows sometimes returns 0 instead of 1

Tags: mysql

I have a strange problem with php scripts - mysql_affected_rows() sometimes returns "0" for no reason.

There is a similar question @stackoverflow and answer to this question is:

*MySQL only actually updates a row if there would be a noticeable difference before and after the updat.*

But this is not my case. For example, if **value before update is 1320402744** and **value after update is 1320402944** mysql_affected_rows() anyway return "0". Is this difference not enough noticable?

Below are 3 files. As you can see, all files include file "functions.inc.php" which calls function "online()".

File "**login.php**" is working fine. It inserts a new row in "session" table correctly.

File "**content.php**" is working fine - it displays content and correctly runs function "online() in "functions.inc.php".

Then I call file "**test.php**". It deletes "something from sometable" correctly. Then it refreshes itself (Header("Location: /test.php");). After refreshing I am logged off.

I added this to "online()" function:

```
echo "affected_rows";
```

It returns **0**.

I added more code to "online() function:

```
$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM session WHERE userid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'") or die('Error');
$found = mysql_num_rows($checkuser);

echo $found;

 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE session SET time='$ctime' WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die('Error');
    $affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();
    if ($affected_rows != 1) @session_destroy();

echo $affected_rows;
```

The result is **1** and **0**.

I checked the database. "time" field in session table has been updated.

So, I can't understand how is it possible that the row exists, it updates correctly but mysql_affected_rows(); returns **0**, and why this happends only if te same page has been refreshed.

**functions.inc.php**

```
<?php
@ob_start();@session_start();
@mysql_connect(C_HOST, C_USER, C_PASS) or die('Cant connect');
@mysql_select_db(C_BASE) or die('Cant select DB');

function online() {
$ctime = time()+1800;

if((isset($_SESSION['id']))&&(is_numeric($_SESSION['id']))) {

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE session SET time='$ctime2' WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die('Error');
$affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();
if ($affected_rows != 1) @session_destroy();
}
}

//many other functions go here

online();
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'configuration.inc.php';
include_once 'functions.inc.php';

//many things go here

$upd = mysql_query("INSERT INTO session VALUES ('" . $i['id'] . "','$ctime')") or die('Error2');
Header("Location: /content.php?justlogged=1");
die;
?>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'configuration.inc.php';
include_once 'functions.inc.php';
//many thing go here
echo "content";

?>
```

**test.php**

```
    <?php
    include_once 'configuration.inc.php';
    include_once 'functions.inc.php';

    if (isset($_GET['tid'])&&(is_numeric($_GET['tid']))){
    $result = mysql_query("delete from some_table where something = '" . $_GET['tid'] . "'") or die('Error123a');
Header("Location: /test.php");
    die;
    }

    //file content

    ?>
```

Comment: can we know your MySQL version ?

Comment: After reading your codes once & again, I can't find the bug. But what I suggest is that, specify the `link identifier` to avoid using wrong DB link.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor, bug in code design. He's calling `online()` for every file, even in login.php.. he's calling `online()`, then inserts new record with session.. then redirects user to content.php where `online()` is called once again. What are timeframes for that? Answer: minimal. This is very likely that seconds everywhere will be the same and of course affected_rows will return `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `function.inc.php` you call `online()` - session time is changed every second. But can it be that you're switching between pages (login, content, test) more faster than 1 second? In that case time would be the same and you'd get session destroy because of unaffected rows

**Edit:**

Yes. As I thought.

See how it comes:

you call login.php: after successful login it creates new session with time `X`. After this you're immediately redirected to content.php (time is still `X`) which calls `online` again. And of course, as you redirected immediately  - time is the same.. so already at point of `content.php` session is already destroyed, because time wasn't changed.

Comment: Vitaly Dyatlov, here are 2 timestamps: 1320405278 before page refresh and 1320405343 after update when session got destroyed.

Comment: @tfe, what do you mean by page refresh? Which page, how page navigating is going? I'd create a file called debug.txt and in function `online` write $user_id and $ctime to that file to ensure that every time you're passing different times there. And log time in login.php too.

Comment: Vitaly, now I understand (See how it comes:...), thank you. So, I can't use mysql_affected_rows in this situation. Don't see any another solution yet. I need it because I want to destroy session for users who have been deleted from "session" table due to inactivity but then they come back and session is still valid but they are not in "session" table and became "ghost" users. I also can't use "ON duplicate KEY UPDATE" because "session" table contains not only user ID but also age, avatar and other information which is written to "session" table when users logs in.

Comment: @tfe, just use `SELECT` before update (to check if user exists). And then update user in session table, without checking for affected rows

Comment: yes, I can do it but it takes +1 MySQL query on each page click. :(

Comment: That's fine. Don't care too much about number of queries.